# custom search in android using google place api

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-nearby

In Google place api their is list of type.But is it possible to enter custom type?
Suppose there is type  store  and if i want specific type like automobile parts store then how to achieve this?

below link gives list of stores in response
 https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=lat,lng&radius=10000&type=store&sensor=true&key=YOUR_API_KEY

How to achieve result of specific-type in response?

Comment: check documentation in my answer for supported google place types in api

Answer (score -1):

You can check google documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types). You can use only these types.